# Cant get value of hidden field after ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that when a link is clicked it opens a pop up box to insert new charges. When this pop up box opens I use jquery load() function to insert a table with all the current charges (loaded from mysql) from a script on another page called load_charges.php.

The problem I am having is I can not access any of the hidden values from the content I just loaded I use:

```
var charge_id = $(':hidden:first', $(this)).val();
```

this normally gets me the value of the first hidden element but it does not work if I am trying get the info from the page load from load_charges.php. I will list my code below:

case_cpanel.php:

//HTML Table with Form elememt

```
<table>
    <tr class="lead_hover">
        <td>
            <form class="calc" title="Case Expense Calculator" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <input type="hidden" id="lead_id" value="21946295" />
                <input type="hidden" id="final_id" value="74" />
                <input name="order" type="hidden" id="final_id" value="3" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lead_hover">
        <td>
            <form class="calc" title="Case Expense Calculator" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <input type="hidden" id="lead_id" value="21978679" />
                <input type="hidden" id="final_id" value="79" />
                <input name="order" type="hidden" id="final_id" value="1" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

// Jquery to load popup form box

```
$(".calc").click(function () {
    var value = $(':hidden:eq(0)', $(this)).val();
    $('input[name=lead_id]').val(value);
    var value = $(':hidden:eq(1)', $(this)).val();
    $('input[name=final_id]').val(value);
    var value = $(':hidden:eq(2)', $(this)).val();
    $('.order').val(value);
    var lead_id = $(':hidden:eq(0)', $(this)).val();
    var string1 = "token=<? echo $_SESSION['token'];  ?>&lead_id=";
    var url = "../ajax/load_charges.php";
    var datastring = string1.concat(lead_id);
    $('#calc_right_display').html('<div><img src="../imgs/loading4.gif" align="center" /></div>').load(url, datastring).show();
    $("#calc_div").overlay().load();
});
```

**load_charges.php:**
// table that is load with new form elements

```
<table width="266" border="0" cellpadding="5">
    <? do { ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="163">
            <? echo $row_charges[ 'rows'][ 'title']; ?>
        </td>
        <td width="83">$
            <? echo $row_charges[ 'rows'][ 'charge']; ?>
        </td>
        <td width="27">
            <form class="delete_charge" title="Delete Charge" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <input type="hidden" id="id1" value "<? echo $row_charges['rows']['id']; ?>">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <? } while ($row_charges[ 'rows']=m ysql_fetch_assoc($row_charges[ 'query'])); ?>
</table>
```

//Jquery Code on load_charges.php

```
<script>
$(".delete_charge").click(function () { * *
    var charge_id = $(':hidden:first', $(this)).val(); * *
    var str2 = "token=<? echo $_REQUEST['token'];  ?>&delete_charge=true&id=";
    var str_lead_id = "&lead_id=<? echo $_REQUEST['lead_id'];  ?>";
    var url2 = "../ajax/cm_expenses_delete.php";
    var datastring2 = str2.concat(charge_id, str_lead_id);

    $('#calc_right_display').html('<div><img src="../imgs/loading4.gif" align="center" /></div>').load(url2, datastring2).show();
});
</script>
```

The problem is var charge_id = $(':hidden:first', $(this)).val(); is not returning any value from the new page that just loaded. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance. 
Ryan

Comment: are you really binding click to form element ??  <form class="delete_charge"

Comment: $(':hidden').first().val() doesn't work?

Comment: Also note that when you do `do...while` _do_ is executed before your variable assignment in _while_. `$row_charges['rows']` will be assigned only after the _while_ loop has ran once.

Answer (score 1):

You may be having a problem retrieving the value because you are missing an equal sign.
This:
`<input type="hidden" id="id1" value"<? echo $row_charges['rows']['id']; ?>">`

Change to:
`<input type="hidden" id="id1" value="<? echo $row_charges['rows']['id']; ?>">`

This would explain it because your input has no value.

Comment: Genius. it is always the simple things that fail. Thank you problem was not jquery but a small syntax error. Thank you user2640147

Comment: You are very welcome! It happens to me all the time. I found it while trying to make a jsfiddle for you. Sometimes we just need another set of eyes. If you have time and this helped, please click the check mark under the down arrow. It would be much appreciated. If you need anymore help, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

I made the following test, based on your data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var charge_id = $('input:hidden:first').val(); 
alert(charge_id);

var charge_id = $('input[type=hidden]:first').val(); 
alert(charge_id);


});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/c4AHM/1/